# MRO error in pyqt4 python

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to inherit widget1 to use its methods but I get :

```
"TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases Cannot create a 
consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases widget1, QWidget"
```

when I run the program. Can you explain to me why this happen?

thank.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class widget1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

class widget2(QtGui.QWidget, widget1):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = widget1()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ... Why would you inherit from both?

Comment: @  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams -Do i have to remove QtGui.QWidget inheritance from widget2 because widget1 has already inherited it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Multiple Inheritance in PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/gotchas.html#multiple-inheritance)

> It is not possible to define a new Python class that sub-classes from
>   more than one Qt class.

There are multiple alternative design decisions you can use, which makes multiple QObject inheritance unnecessary.

#### Simple inherit from the single parent class

```
class widget1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(widget1, self).__init__()

    def foo(self): pass
    def bar(self): pass

class widget2(widget1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(widget2, self).__init__()

    def foo(self): print "foo"
    def baz(self): pass
```

#### Composition

```
class widget2(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(widget2, self).__init__()
        self.widget1 = widget1()
```

#### Make one of the classes a mixin class, which is not a QObject:

```
class widget1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(widget1, self).__init__()

    def foo(self): print "foo"
    def bar(self): pass

class MixinClass(object):
    def someMethod(self):
        print "FOO"

class widget2(widget1, MixinClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(widget2, self).__init__()

    def bar(self): self.foo()
    def baz(self): self.someMethod()
```

Comment: In the 1st and 3rd examples both Widget1 and Widget2 could have inherited from the same BaseWidget class

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That seems like a 4th example on its own, though